# Haskell- composing three functions in weird way

Tags: haskell, composition

I have three functions x y z and a function called functionComposer.

I want functionComposer to have as arguments the functions x y z and to return me a function that uses the result of y and z as arguments into x and applies x.

In mathematical notation: `x(y(a),z(b))`

**Im NOT asking for this : `functionComposer x y z = x.y.z`**

For example:

```
double x = x + x

summer x y = x + y

functionComposer summer double double = summer (double) (double)
```

if x = 2 the result should be 8   (2+2)+(2+2)

Comment: Your description is confusing; you initially say you have x and y as functions, a and b as args, but at the end you talk about an arg called x.

Comment: You can literally write what you already wrote and haskell will accept it :  `\x y z a b -> x(y(a),z(b))`. Or without a tuple and extra parentheses: `\x y z a b -> x (y a) (z b)`

Comment: The problem with that is that if funcion y or z need more than one parameter the funcion would not work. I said that i got it just to be nice. But to be honest the solution here is just parcial. It works only if y and z are of the type y::a->c z::b->d . I was looking for a general solution.

Comment: for example. If i define a function: composer f1 f2 f3 = f1.f2.f3 the type of f3 is not necesary a->b , it can have more than one argument, it can be a->b->c->d or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow feel as if you wanted a confusing series of dots anyways, so:

```
functionComposer :: (c -> d -> e) -> (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> a -> b -> e
functionComposer x y z = (. z) . (x . y)
```

which comes “naturally” from

```
functionComposer x y z a = (x . y) a . z
```

But why stop there?

```
functionComposer x y = (. (x . y)) . flip (.)
```

No, more:

```
functionComposer x = (. flip (.)) . flip (.) . (x .)
```

More!

```
functionComposer = (((. flip (.)) . flip (.)) .) . (.)
```

Comment: Something like this i was looking for. The point is that you are limiting the arguments that y and z can have. I dont want to define the type of y and z. I want them to be generinc functions that we know nothing about. If we define function composer without defining its type haskell should be able to infere the type of x y z (i believe...) and that would make the function more useful

Comment: For example, the previous point of this homework was to compone a function like this composingMachine1 x y z = x.y.z and the type of the function was                                                composingMachine :: t1 -> t2 -> (t1 -> t2 -> t) ->t

Comment: @user3630355, all of the answers are generic.

Comment: Sorry if im extremely noobish                              but, in this case functionComposer x y z = (. z) . (x . y) the function is processing y and the result of that goes into x and the reslts of that goes into z right? If you can explaint it step by step i would be grateful.

Comment: That by itself is a little hard to explain, so let’s start with the full expansion of `functionComposer x y z a b = x (y a) (z b)`. That can be turned into `x (y a)` on `z`, so `functionComposer x y z a = x (y a) . z`. `x (y a)` can also be written `(x . y) a`, so it’s `functionComposer x y z a = (x . y) a . z`. That can be written `(.) ((x . y) a) z`, which can be written `flip (.) z ((x . y) a)`, and then it’s possible to take the `a` out in the same way as earlier as `flip (.) z . (x . y)`. `flip (.) z` is `(. z)`, so the whole thing ends up as `(. z) . (x . y)`.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the applicative instance for `(->) a` like so

```
import Control.Applicative


funcComp summer double1 double2 = summer <$> double1 <*> double2
```

Or the monad instance

```
funcComp summer double1 double2 = liftM2 summer double1 double2
```

The way to understand this is that for `(->) a`, both the applicative and the monad instance are meant to "parametrize" over the function value that `double1` and `double2` both accept.

Comment: Lovely lovely Applicative. mmmmmm.

Comment: So, essentially, `funcComp = liftA2`.

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 5):

Using your notation:

```
functionComposer summer double1 double2 = \x -> summer (double1 x) (double2 x)
```

The `\x -> ...` represents the function mapping `x` to the `...`.

Note I had to give different names to the `double` function argument, since in general you want to compose different functions.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically evaluating `y` and `z` "in parallel<sup>1</sup>". The most fundamental combinator to express this is [`(***) :: Arrow f => f a c -> f b d -> f (a, b) (c, d)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v%3a-42--42--42-). The result of that you want to feed to `x`, so basically you'd like to write

```
           x . (y***z)            -- or  x <<< y***z
```

Now that doesn't quite do the trick because the arrow combinators work with tuples. So you need to uncurry `x`. Much the same way, if you want the entire thing to accept the arguments in the normal curried fashion, then you must curry out the `(a,b)` tuple. Easy enough though:

```
functionComposer :: (c -> d -> e) -> (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> a -> b -> e
functionComposer x y z = curry $ uncurry x <<< y *** z
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Mind, I don't mean parallel in the multithreading sense, only "semantically parallel".